# Map in Array list

Tags: scala

I am new in scala/spark so could you please help me about this:

I have this:

```
val list= Array(("a",(1,2,3)),("b",(1,2))
```

I want to have in output :

```
(a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(b,1),(b,2)
```

What can I do to have this.

Comment: What does this have to do with Spark ? This is basic Scala.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `productIterator` to iterate over the tuples. The following results in `List[(String, Any)] = List((a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (b,1), (b,2))`. Not sure if there is a nice way to infer that the types of the items in all your tuples is `Integer` instead of `Any` though.

```
val list: Array[(String, Product)]= Array(("a",(1,2,3)),("b",(1,2)))

(for {
  i <- list.iterator
  n <- i._2.productIterator
} yield {
  (i._1, n)
}).toList
```

Answer (score 0):

You would only need to do this:

```
list.flatMap(t => t._2.productIterator.map(n => t._1->n))
```

Personally i wouldn't use dynamic tuples :/ I would use lists of ints or something.